# Exploiting the PHP readfile function when a filename is appended to the path

Tags: php, exploit

I would like to ask a question about exploiting the PHP function `readfile`.
So I'm geting payed for hacking a site, and I need to read a PHO file named `readme.php` through a PHP file named `read.php`, that contains the following code:

```
<?php
$path = $_GET['p'];
readfile("pages/$path/index.html");
?>
```

So I can't read the `readme.php` file because it automatically adds the `/index.html`. In this case, is there a way to read the PHP file?

Comment: @silverpenguin  you need to try this attack for yourself.  There are multiple reasons why that is an invalid payload.  PHP patched nullbyte injection for file-io functions, and **that isn't a null byte injection payload**.

Answer (score 6):

Beside PHP is interpreted, version <= to PHP 5.3.4 are vulnerable to an attack commonly call **null byte injection**.

To declare a string in php, you use `$var = "hey"` which is then equivalent in C to `char tab[4]="hey"`. Notice that we declared a 4 bytes array of characters while we only want to store 3 characters. This is because compiler automatically insert the null byte character. Your final string is then `hey\0`

`tab` is a pointer which point on the first character of your string. Your computer will read from the first character to the null byte character (0 in hexadecimal) represented by `\0`.

`%00` is the representation of the null byte character in PHP.

When you are calling a function with a string, like `readfile("pages/$path/index.html");`, your string get stored in a variable. Let's call it `$tmp=pages/pathFromVariable/index.html` which in reality will be stored in memory as `pages/pathFromVariable/index.html\0`

Now, if you inject null byte at the end of your input, you can erase the end of the string. for example, if `$tmp=pages/pathFromVariable%00/index.html` it will be stored as `pages/pathFromVariable\0/index.html\0` which will result into reading the file `pages/pathFromVariable` ! Pwned !